# What is the verb tense for the word hunger in Matthew 5:6

Tags: matthew

What is the verb tense for hunger as used in Matthew 5:6

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  You can find direct answers to this type of quoin from a well-used site, https://biblehub.com/matthew/5-6.htm for any Bible text.

Answer (score 1):

The verb tense is present. It is a participle conjugated in the present tense and active voice, and declined in the nominative case, masculine gender, and plural number, from the lemma (lexical form) πεινάω.